# Put an initial condition on some parameter

Tags: assumptions

Good morning,
I'm new in the world of Mathematica, so I'm sorry if my question isn't very relevant.
I'm trying to solve a system of 5 equations withs many parameters. To be clear, I will hit the core of my problem. Here is my code :

```
$Assumptions = q > 1;
C1[a_, q] := -(7/5) + (7 a)/5 + 2 q; //** here a is a real number and q is a real number strictly grater than 1
Reduce[C11[a, q] <= 0, a]
```

The answer that I got is "q ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ && a <= 1/7 (7 - 10 q). This means that my code didn't take the assumption on q. Please could you propose a method to solve this issue ?

Of course my system contains a lot of parameters with different constraints to be injected (bit I avoid it here)
Thank you for helping

Comment: @cvgmt I want to reduce the expression with respect to a. When I wrote what you proposed, I get " q>1 is not a valid variable"

Comment: You need to specify the condition inside Reduce like: `Reduce[{C1[a, q] <= 0, q > 1}, a]`

Comment: `Clear[C1, a, q]; 
C1[a_, q_] = -(7/5) + (7 a)/5 + 2 q; Reduce[{C1[a, q] <= 0, q > 1}, a]`

Comment: @DanielHuber @@cvgmt Thank you for your answers. With your help, I got `q >1 && a <= 1/7 (7 - 10 q)`

Comment: Note that `FreeQ[Options[Reduce], Assumptions]` gives `True`, so of course `Reduce[]` is not going to be affected by setting `$Assumptions`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your answer